# Test activities in instrumentation app

Tags: android, testing

I'm trying to use test specific activities in my instrumentation tests but keep getting

`Unable to resolve activity for: Intent {}`

I declared the activity in the android manifest of the instrumentation test module but the test runner doesn't seem able to find it.

Is what I'm trying to do impossible? To be clear, I want to declare those test activities in my instrumentation module, not in the application. The only purpose of those activities is to facilitate the test of complex scenarios where mocking doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some code of the instrumentation or application, or maybe be more specifically about what are you trying to do?

Comment: For example, I'd like to have an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> where T is an Activity in my instrumentation test module, not in the application. This is useful to help drive some more complex integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this won't work. The instrumentation test system assumes that T is in the app under test.

Comment: It doesn't specifically need to be ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> where T is an Activity in my instrumentation test module. The solution could evolve something else as long as I can involve an activity in the instrumentation package somehow. Could a custom test runner help?

Answer (score 0):

You can test an Activity that doesn't appear in any manifest using ActivityUnitTestCase - which may or may not be suitable for your tests.

You should also consider Robolectric, which also doesn't require that you declare activities in the manifest.

If you do need to use ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, the way I have been handling this case is to declare the extra test activities in the debug build's manifest. It's not ideal, but at least this way those entries don't make it into the release builds.

(Interestingly, the actual Java code for the Activity can be in the instrumentation module rather than the app under test)